# PostgreSQL 9.3:Dynamic Cross tab query

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab, postgresql-9.3

I am really new to PostgreSQL using version is 9.3.

Well I have the following table with some records:

**Example**:

```
create table tst
(
cola varchar(10),
colc varchar(10)
)

insert into tst values('101','A1');
insert into tst values('101','A2');
insert into tst values('201','A3');
insert into tst values('301','A4');
insert into tst values('401','A1');
insert into tst values('101','A6');
insert into tst values('201','A1');
insert into tst values('201','A5');
```

**Note**: Now I want to show only that records in which `cola` belongs to `colc`'s values. If the user pass the `colc` values as a parameter to function then it has to match the exact value of `colc` belongs to which `cola` value.

**Expected Result**:

If the user pass `A1,A2,A6` then the result should be:

```
cola   A1   A2   A6
--------------------
101    1    1    1
```

**Note**: In the above result the record `101` appears because it belongs to `A1,A2,A6` not other values. `201` not appear because that belongs to `A1,A3` and `A5` also.

If the user pass `A1` then the result should be:

```
cola   A1 
----------
401    1
```

**Note**: In the above result the record `401` appears because it belongs to only `A1`.

I am not getting how to write crosstab within function for this scenario.

Comment: refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server-side function cannot have a dynamic return type in PostgreSQL, so obtaining the mentioned result as-is from a fixed function is not possible.

Also, it does not look much like a typical crosstab problem, anyway. The `cola` part of the output can be obtained by filtering over an aggregate, and the other columns `A1/A2/A6` are actually the input, so copying them as columns into the output is easy in the context of a client-side generated query.

The gist of an actual SQL query finding the matching rows would be:

```
select cola from ts
group by cola
having array_agg(colc order by colc)='{A1,A2,A6}'
```

This will find `101`.

Adding the other columns is a just a client-side presentation problem. For instance, the query could be written like this:

```
select cola, 1 as A1, 1 as A2, 1 as A6 from tst
group by cola
having array_agg(colc order by colc)='{A1,A2,A6}';
```

result:

```
 cola | a1 | a2 | a6 
------+----+----+----
 101  |  1 |  1 |  1
```